# Set Text not working in dialogue box android

Tags: android, android-edittext, settext

I am currently working on a project where when the user clicks on an email button it will take him to a dialogue box where his email is already inserted in the edit text but the problem i am facing is that the `setText` function is not being implemented. 
Here is my code:

```
Button Emailbtn = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnEmail);
Emailbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    v.setSelected(true);
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(ViewQuotesD.this);
    dialog.getWindow();
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialemail);

    //Getting content for email
    final Button btnsend = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnEmail);
    btnsend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        final EditText emaill = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.edtEmail);
        emaill.setText(SlectedName);

        String email = emaill.getText().toString().trim();
        String subject = "Your Quotations";
        String message = "Hi " + SelectedEmail +" "+SelectedSurname+"\n"+
                         "FABRIC: \n"+
                         "Total price of fabric = R" + SelectedFabricTotal+
                         "\n"+
                         "LINING: \n"+
                          "Total price of lining = R" + SelectedLiningtotal+
                          "\n"+
                          "LABOUR: \n"+
                          "Total labour cost on fabric = R" + SelectedFabricLabour+
                          "\n"+
                          "VOIL: \n"+
                          "Total price of voil = R" + SelectedVoilTotal +"\n"+
                          "Labour price on voil = R" + SelectedVoilLabour+
                           "\n"+
                           "RAILINGS: \n"+
                           "Total price of railings = R" + SelectedRailTotal+
                           "\n"+
                           "VALANCE: \n"+
                           "Total price of valance = R" + SelectedValTotal+
                           "\n"+
                           "INSTALLATION: \n"+
                           "Total installation cost = R" + SelectedInstall+
                           "\n"+
                           "GRAND TOTAL = R" + SelectedPrice;

        //Creating SendMail object
        SendMail sm = new SendMail(ViewQuotesD.this, email, subject, message);

        //Executing sendmail to send email
        sm.execute();
        finish();
        startActivity(getIntent());
        Toast.makeText(ViewQuotesD.this , "Email sent" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
    });
  }
});
dialog.show();
```

I have tested to see if the variable is being parsed and it is, it is just not being implemented on the `SetText` even if I try a normal string for example `Emaill.setText("test");` it still doesn't show.

Comment: You could try to refresh the view using `emaill.invalidate()`. I doubt it will solve the issue, but it might still be worth a shot.

Comment: @Markaos nope didnt work unfortunately

Comment: Please rebuild the project or select invalidate cache and restart in File menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the logical of codes is correct, please check the layout xml file, maybe the content of `EditText` has already changed, but it doesn't display because of text color is same as background color.

Try change `Edittext` color to test .